# SDL web 8 | Multiple Publication same target Mapping

Tags: publishing, web8, topology-manager

Is it possible to map multiple publications with same target location So that pages published with all publications can have same destination. I have a publication called "A" which publish the pages to Staging and Live Target.

I have another publication"B" added which inherits publication "A". I can see the targets in publication B , I can see the option for publishing but when I click publish button It doesn't send the page to publishing queue.

This is the result of get-ttmmapping command.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> get-ttmmapping


CmEnvironmentId     : Tridioncm_local
PublicationId       : tcm:0-1-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Staging
WebApplicationId    : web8Stagingdemo_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://web8stagingdemo:82/
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       :
Id                  : web8StagingdemoMapping
ExtensionProperties : {}

CmEnvironmentId     : Tridioncm_local
PublicationId       : tcm:0-1-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Live
WebApplicationId    : web8demo_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://web8demo:82/
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       :
Id                  : web8demoMapping
ExtensionProperties : {}
```

I am trying to add mapping something like this but it doesn''t work.

```
Add-TtmMapping -Id web8StagingdemoENMapping -PublicationID tcm:0-4-1 -WebApplicationId web8Stagingdemo_RootWebApp
```

Comment: Are you able to see any error message while running this command? If yes, Can you update your question with the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can map multiple Publications to the same Web Application, as long as you ensure they have distinct URLs. This means that each Mapping in Topology Manager (for the same Web Application) must have a distinct `RelativeUrl` property.

Note that the  `RelativeUrl` defaults to empty, so you will have to specify it explicitly on the `Add-TtmMapping` command.

Comment: So something like this should work? `Add-TtmMapping -Id web8StagingdemoENMapping -PublicationID tcm:0-4-1 -WebApplicationId web8Stagingdemo_RootWebApp -RelativeUrl /en` as long as /en is not in use?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved by creating a new webApplication with a unique id, adding it to the existing website with the relative url. 
Then map this unique webapplication id to the publication.

```
PS C:\SDL_WebServices_Staging\discovery\config> Add-TtmWebApplication -Id web8StagingDemo_ENWebApp

cmdlet Add-TtmWebApplication at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
WebsiteId: web8Stagingdemo
ContextUrl: /en



PS C:\SDL_WebServices_Staging\discovery\config> Add-TtmMapping

cmdlet Add-TtmMapping at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
PublicationId: tcm:0-4-1
WebApplicationId: web8StagingDemo_ENWebApp
```

Comment: Do you really use distinct Web Applications to serve these two Publications? If so, this is the proper way to model your infrastructure in Topology Manager.  If not (for example you use a single DXA Web Application to serve multiple Publications), it is better to create a single WebApplication and use multiple Mappings with distinct RelativeUrls.